# Which tool can help generate a SQL server 2005/2008 database from E-R diagram?

Tags: sql-server, uml

In Visio 2003 Architect version I can generate a SQL Server Database on the fly from UML ER diagram. But there is no such a way by using Visio 2007. My question is: Any other good and latest tools can support ER-> DB or DB->ER very well for SQL2005/2008?

Comment: The architect version is not available for Visio 2007.  Have you tried using the Visio 2003 Architect version against SQL Server 2005/2008 instead?  I believe you can run them side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a free/open source tool to achieve this, you could try:

[DBDesigner](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/index.php)

From the website:

> DBDesigner 4 is a visual database design system that integrates database design, modeling, creation and maintenance into a single, seamless environment.
>
> It combines professional features and a clear and simple user interface to offer the most efficient way to handle your databases.
>
> DBDesigner 4 compares to products like Oracle's Designer©, IBM's Rational Rose©, Computer Associates's ERwin© and theKompany's DataArchitect© but is an Open Source Project available for Microsoft Windows© 2k/XP and Linux KDE/Gnome. It is release on the GPL.

And it supports the following features:

> - Available on Linux / MS Windows
> - User Interfaced based on industry standard layouting software
> - Design Mode / Query Mode
> - **Reverse engineering MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL and any ODBC databases**
> - Userdefined schema-generation
> - **Model-To-Database syncronisation**
> - Index support
> - Automatic foreign key placement
> - Weak entity support
> - Standard Inserts storing and sync
> - Full documentation capabilities
> - Advanced model printing
> - Output as image
> - All MySQL datatypes with all options
> - User defined datatypes
> - Database storage, ability to save model within database
> - Network-/Multiuser access through database storage
> - Version control*
> - SQL Query Builder
> - SQL Command History
> - SQL Command storage within model
> - Plugin interface

I think the bolded ones above (my own emphasis) should give you what you require (i.e. effectively two-way database/model synchronization).

I have used the tool in the past to reverse engineer an existing database to an ER diagram.  From what I remember, it wasn't the most stable software I'd ever used (I seem to recall it crashed a couple of times) however, this was a little while ago so it may be more stable now.

Answer (score 2):

I think Enterprise Architect can do that too.

http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/

Answer (score 2):

You can do the ER diagram on Visual Studio creating a dbml file and then export to a Sql Server script using the huagati plugin. http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Answer (score 0):

I remember that in Visio 2003 that was only possible, I believe in the Enterprise Edition.  Could that be your issue with 2007?

Comment: Well it has Professional and Standard Editions, but as Cade said, no Architect version.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the tools don't handle SQL 2005/2008 correctly. But [CA ERwin® Process Modeler](http://www.ca.com/us/products/product.aspx?id=254) does the best job (at a cost though).

There is a [community edition](http://www.ca.com/us/products/Product.aspx?ID=8242) but it is limited to 25 objects per model.

Give it a try and let us know.